# Can I get Visual Studio to invoke MSBuild.exe for builds?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012

When you trigger a build in Visual Studio, it uses the MSBuild libraries to run the build. However, if the build hangs (and sometimes it does) this means that I have to kill `devenv.exe`.

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to invoke `MSBuild.exe` (so that I can kill that), instead of using MSBuild programmatically?

Comment: Umm, it's unusual, because on my machine - VS2012 is the first version which actually invokes msbuild.exe, instead of loading msbuild libraries in devenv.exe. BTW VS2010 did load libs in context, but 2012 calls msbuild exe directly and you can kill it freely. It even works fine with 1 in "maximum number of parallel project builds" (Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run).

Answer (score 3):

It is not common for a build to hang. IMHO you should check that before trying to bypass the problem. Anyway, you could use MSBuild as an external tool:

Tools -> External Tools -> Add

Fill the form with these values:

- Title - MSBuild
- Command - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
- Arguments - $(SolutionName)
- Initial Directory - $(SolutionDir)

Check "Use Output Window".

Then you can invoke the command in the "Tools" menu.